# Why plot(..., show_last = true ? na : 10) works like show_last = 0 (not na)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Why `plot(..., show_last = true ? na : 10)` works like `show_last = 0` and not like  `show_last = na`?
(please run this on 1H and try changing the input)

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='PLOT show_last', shorttitle='PLOT show_last', overlay=true)

showHistory = input.bool(true, title='Show History')

FHFastEMA = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '240', ta.ema(close, 240))

var lbl = label.new(bar_index, low, text = "(showHistory ? na : 1) = " + str.tostring(showHistory ? na : 1) + "\nshowHistory = " + str.tostring(showHistory), style =  label.style_label_up, color = color.yellow, xloc = xloc.bar_index)

lbl.set_xy(bar_index, low)

plot(FHFastEMA, title='4 Hours Fast EMA', style=plot.style_line, color=color.white, linewidth = 4, show_last = showHistory ? na : 10)
plot(FHFastEMA, title='4 Hours Fast EMA', style=plot.style_line, color=color.yellow,  show_last = na)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `show_last=` parameter only takes *input/const* values, when you declare a conditional statement Pine creates a *series* variable under the hood, and *series* variables are not compatible with the *show_last* parameter. It only saves the first condition at compile time and does not change it at runtime.

The workaround in your case is to use the input value passed directly to the show_last parameter, avoiding creating a series in between.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='PLOT show_last', shorttitle='PLOT show_last', overlay=true)

showHistoryLast = input.int(10, "How Many History bars to show")

FHFastEMA = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '240', ta.ema(close, 240))

plot(FHFastEMA, title='4 Hours Fast EMA', style=plot.style_line, color=color.white, linewidth = 4, show_last = showHistoryLast)
plot(FHFastEMA, title='4 Hours Fast EMA', style=plot.style_line, color=color.yellow,  show_last = na)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the workaround. However, I still do not understand - I would expect that at compile time `showHistory ? na : 1` would be evaluated as `na`. But based on the results I guess it is evaluated as `0`.

Comment: In this case only the first condition of the ternary operator `showHistory ? na : 1`, and the rest are ignored at runtime. The show_last= operator expects to pass an integer value, `na` is a `not-a-value` which is not a valid integer.

Comment: So, does show_last= convert `na` to `0` silently?